# Bash, How to check command output and proceed

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash script that rsyncs my files to my remote server. I want to check if there are lines with "import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()" before syncing, but I can't. This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash;
var="$1" ;

if [ "$var" == "main" -o "$var" == "all" ] ; then
    echo "*** checking of ipdb lines, first ***" ;
    res=$(ack-grep --type=python "import ipdb" -c -l) ; 
    if [ $res ] ; then
        echo $res ; 
    else
        rsync -Paz --exclude ".*" -e "ssh -i /home/chris/.ssh/thishost-rsync-key" this_pc remote_pc 
    fi
fi
```

I always get this type of error:

```
*** checking of ipdb lines, first ***
sync.sh: line 10: [: too many arguments
sending incremental file list
```

Line 10 in my script is this one: `if [ $res ] ; then`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your first line should be either `if [[ $var == main || $var == all ]]` or `if [ "$var" = main ] || [ "$var" = all ]`; don't use `==` with `[...]` (although `bash` allows it, you should be using `[[ ... ]]` when available) and the POSIX spec recommends not using `-o` any more as the `or` operator, due to possible ambiguities in parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
res=$(ack-grep --type=python "import ipdb" -c -l) ;
```

the variable `$res` is set to contain the *output* from the command(s) inside `$(...)`.

If you want the resulting exit status use `$?` instead, otherwise use e.g.

```
if [ ! -z "$res" ] ...
```

to check if `$res` is not empty (meaning that there was output from the command).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of :

```
if [ $res ] ; then
```

Use:

```
if [ ! -z "$res" ] ; then
```

- `-z` `=>` return True if the length of string is zero.